# Downloading PDF files with Scrapy

Tags: python, session, cookies, scrapy

I'm scraping pdf files from a site using Scrapy, a Python web-scraping framework.

The site requires to follow the same session in order to allow you to download the pdf.

It works great with Scrapy's because it's all automated but when I run the script after a couple of seconds it starts to give me fake pdf files like when I try to access directly the pdf, without my session.

Why is that so & any idea how to overcome this problem!?

Comment: Request them slower? I bet they are rate-limiting you.

Comment: You are right about that, but it needs a longer time-break & with that download rate I can't finish my task because a need to download a huge amount of pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the site tracks your session. If it's a PHP site, pass PHPSESSID cookie to the request which downloads the PDF file.